# Double action in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

Simple and stupid question. I have simple site. On the main site I have also searcher, and I can search articles in db with typed string.
After 'click' URL looks:
`https://localhost:44336/Home/SearchString?SearchString=SearchedString`
Why is SearchString doubled?

My View (with searcher):

```
<form asp-controller="Home"  asp-action="SearchString" method="get">
        <p>
            Keyword: <input type="text" name="SearchString" />
            <input type="submit" />
            <br>
        </p>
    </form>
```

My Controller looks:

```
 public IActionResult SearchString(String word)
        {
            var art = _articleRepository.SearchArticles(word);
            return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", art);
        }
```

and ArticleRepo:

```
public IEnumerable<Article> SearchArticles(String word)
        {
            
            var arts = from m in _applicationDbContext.Articles select m;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
            {
                arts = arts.Where(x => x.Content.Contains(word));
            }
           
            return arts.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Not used to seeing such a minimal and simplified example for asp.net questions.  +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a double action.  It is a single action and a single parameter, both of which happen to have the same name.

The first 'SearchString' is because of `asp-action="SearchString"`.  It tells the engine to look for the method by that name on your controller.

The second 'SearchString' is because of `name="SearchString"`.  You may want to try `name="word"` instead, or I believe you can get rid of the name parameter altogether here.  But certainly you can't name it 'SearchString'.

Comment: Yes! That's work! As I said - simple and stupid question ;) The simplest ways are the best. Thank you a lot. I can add only one "thumb up"